# Understanding SQL Database Project workflow

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, tfs

The build process for my SQL 2008 Database Project takes upwards of 15 minutes for 1 build.  I only need to manage roughly 50 stored procedures.  I created a database project and a server project.

Next thing I do is fix all the build errors.  Now I modify a stored procedure.  Then I have to build the entire database and script the entire database just to see if my stored procedure compiles.

Is there any way to test the stored procedure without going through a 15 minute build - then deploy the script?  Can I build just changes instead of the entire DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go with [MSSCCI](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bce06506-be38-47a1-9f29-d3937d3d88d6/).  It's simple UI which plugs directly into SSMS and behaves like Team Explorer is exactly what I've been searching for.  [Getting started.](http://blog.discountasp.net/using-team-foundation-server-2010-source-control-from-sql-server-management-studio/)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should look at why your builds take so long. Maybe you need more memory or something.

Second, why do you have to script the entire database to test the stored procedure? Just deploy to a test database, or even your local sandbox database.

Comment: I'm not sure how deploying to another database will help.  The 15 minute process is all pre-deployment, just stuff that is required to build the script itself.  AFAIK, from the MSDN documents the entire script must be created.  You can create partial projects, but those still go back to the main DB and build it all...

Comment: No, it doesn't create the entire script. Deployment produces a change script relative to the deployment target. Deploying to a sandbox database which has just enough data for testing will give you a database in which to test your stored procedure. I already said you have to look at why your builds are taking so long - 15 minutes is a long time. How many database objects do you have?

Comment: 10's of thousands, probly close to 100,000 in total.  I only manage about 50-100 total of these items.  The build happens on my devbox.  Its a new box, win 7, 8 cores, x64, 8GB RAM.  Hard drive works its #$@ off during the build.

Comment: Ok, that explains a lot. At the same time, I would still explore the possibility that you're hitting memory limits and therefore paging; or that the disk needs to be defragmented; or that other processes are using some of the CPU you'd like to use for your builds.

Comment: +1 - Thanks for the help.  I decided to use a different, simpler product.

Answer (score -1):

I've never used visual studios to "build" and maintain databases.  This, I'd guess, will quickly become unmanageable as the database starts getting bigger.  And I'm assuming when you "build" it, it's verifying and deploying all objects in the database.

I would suggest you do not use visual studios in this fashion. Just maintain your sql code independently.  And store them in version control systems manually.  That way you can update each stored procs separately.  In other words, keep each stored proc as a file.

```
if object_id(<ProcName>) is not null
    drop proc <ProcName>
GO

create proc <ProcName>
...
GO
```

Then, store that as ProcName.sql and let source control handle the rest.  Sorry if this isn't helpful or if I'm just stating the obvious.

Comment: You are the second programmer who has made the file level recommendation.  I may have to drop back to svn.  My concern is that is more training the team needs to endure.

Comment: I think file level storage of the objects is so crude that your developers should be able pick it up rather quickly.  I believe VS can be useful when you're first designing the database but to use that beyond the initial implementation is not efficient.  Good luck!

Comment: -1: if you don't know about database projects, then why are you answering the question?